# Something like ContainsPoint in Scenekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, computational-geometry, scenekit

Simple question: is there anything like the **Spritekit** `containsPoint` method in **SceneKit**?

I guess hit test could work, but I think that that is only for checking which object a 2D touch hits.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to know if a point is contained within the volume defined by a geometry?

Comment: @mnuages exactly

Answer (score 1):

`SCNGeometry` and `SCNNode` both conforms to [SCNBoundingVolume](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnboundingvolume) protocol, which gives access to the bounding box and bounding sphere properties.

> ```
> var boundingBox: (min: SCNVector3, max: SCNVector3)
> ```
>
> The minimum and maximum corner points of the object’s bounding box.
>
> ```
> var boundingSphere: (center: SCNVector3, radius: Float)
> ```
>
> The center point and radius of the object’s bounding sphere.

If the target is a `SCNVector3` point, it's easy to determine whether a box or a sphere contains it using geometry knowledge.

Not sure if the above answers your question. If you want to convert 2D to 3D and vice versa or check if the point is within the camera frustrum, there are useful methods in [SCNSceneRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer) adopted by `SCNView` that you can use to do so.

Comment: Is it possible to get more info, such as a link, on "If the target is a SCNVector3 point, it's easy to determine whether a box or a sphere contains it using geometry knowledge."? Thanks